# Jacobi vs Gauss-Seidel

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Hey guys I'm studying for an exam and I have a problem with this question, can someone help ?

Give two examples of a system of three linear equations. The first example of a situation where the Jacobi method does not converge and the Gauss-Seidl converges, while the second example is the opposite case.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. It would be better if you show your efforts. Wheer are you exactly stuck?

Comment: I know convergence conditions for both methods. 
For the first case i came with matrix: 
\begin{bmatrix}5&7&6\\7&10&8\\6&8&10\end{bmatrix}
This matrix is not strictly diagonal so it wont converge for Jacobi method but its positive definite matrix so it should converge for Gauss-Seidel. I cant think of the opposite case. Pls correct me if Im wrong
@TitoEliatron

Comment: Please provide this useful information in the post, not as a comment !

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2605318/805029) provides an example for the Jacobi-convergent & GS divergent case.